# Batch NFT mining

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, nft, mining, erc-721

I am trying to create a project where users can specify a total supply on a minted NFT, will the NFT all have the same address but with different tokenId's or they will have different addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They’ll have the same contract address as the original minted NFTs and different token Ids

Comment: and different tokenId

Comment: Yes they'll have different tokenIds